# How can pop all tab stack on changing tab in ionic?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, tabs, ionic3

My current tab code stacks all pages one over one for separate tabs. So when I change tabs it shows me previous stacked pages, I want to set all tabs to root when I change tab. Here is my current code

```js
export class TabsPage {

  tab1Root = HomePage;
  tab2Root = SearchPage;
  tab3Root = QueuesPage;
  tab4Root = FavoritesPage;
  tab5Root = SettingsPage;

  constructor() {

  }
}
```

```html
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Home" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Search" tabIcon="search"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Queues" tabIcon="people"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab4Root" tabTitle="Favorites" tabIcon="star"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab5Root" tabTitle="Settings" tabIcon="cog"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Comment: Could you please create a Stackblitz demo?

Comment: here is the demo https://ionic-8jshrq.stackblitz.io . 1st click page 1 button on the home tab, then click any other tab and back to home tab. page 1 is still showing on the home tab. I want when I change tab, tab goes to its root @sebaferreras

Comment: Could you please share the link from the Stackblitz code editor so we can modify the code? Thanks :)

Comment: here it is https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-8jshrq @sebaferreras

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to achieve what you're looking for by getting the reference of the tabs component, and then by getting access to the `NavController` from the previous tab to call the `popToRoot()` method:

```
<!-- #myTabs allow us to get a reference of the tabs -->
<!-- (ionChange) allow us to run our method every time the selected tab is changed -->
<ion-tabs #myTabs (ionChange)="onTabsChange()">
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Home" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="About" tabIcon="information-circle"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Contact" tabIcon="contacts"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

And then:

```
// Angular
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

// Pages
import { AboutPage } from '../about/about';
import { ContactPage } from '../contact/contact';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';

// Tabs
import { Tabs } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {

  @ViewChild('myTabs') tabRef: Tabs;

  tab1Root = HomePage;
  tab2Root = AboutPage;
  tab3Root = ContactPage;

  onTabsChange() {
    // Get the previous tab if any
    const previousTab = this.tabRef.previousTab(false);

    if(previousTab) {
      try {
        // Get the navCtrl and pop to the root page
        previousTab.getViews()[0].getNav().popToRoot();
      } catch(exception) {
        // Oops...
        console.error(exception);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

### [Stackblitz Project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/close-open-tabs)

[image]

Comment: Excelent! Like a charm!!

Comment: Glad to hear that :) @NicolasPapp

Answer (score 0):

For **Ionic 4/5,** I used this solution in my case and it solves me for what I need:

In the `<ion-tab-button>`, I had to combine tab with **routerLink** and it works perfectly for me: The reason? I found no other way without using the eventHandler, navController and without handling lifecycle:

```
<ion-tab-button class="dashboard__button" tab="beneficiaries" routerLink="/dashboard/beneficiaries">
```

So every time you exit and return, it will always be for the root page.

**-Link reference:** [Goto first page in tab when tab change](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/goto-first-page-in-tab-when-tab-change/66406/4?u=1antares1)

Comment: This works because `routerLink` is an Angular directive (https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink), which will handle the URL directly; in contrast, if you use `href`, the URL will be handled by Ionic Router, which has this odd default behavior of navigation to views instead of URLs.

Comment: Adding for reference — this is the exact Ionic line of code which handles this: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/blob/3c1be89112d464e77d65c875223138aaedf350cd/angular/src/directives/navigation/ion-tabs.ts#L126